# Why would you use `extern void my_func();` rather than including `my_utils.h`?

Tags: c, extern

I'm working on some code I didn't write and noticed that there are many `extern void my_func();`.

My understanding is that `extern` in for global variables, not for functions.

Is there a practical reason to declare a function as `extern` rather than putting it in a header file and including that? Or is this just a stylistic choice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is only needed if, for some reason, the header file doesn't declare the function.  And `extern` is always unnecessary for functions, as functions are always `extern` by default.

Comment: functions are always extern by default in C? are you sure??

Comment: @Donotalo: Pretty sure, but it is midnight, so who knows what tiredness has done to my brain.

Comment: i'm working for micro controller for 2 years. the compiler i use is C. though not completely ANSI C, and many features of C99 are absent, but to call a non-static function defined in another file we need to `extern` its prototype, or include the header.

Comment: @Donotalo: Then your compiler is broken.  `#include`-ing a header file with function prototypes is equivalent to writing the prototypes directly into your source file, and you don't see header files full of explicit `extern` functions!

Comment: no we don't put `extern` functions in header. we have to put it in .c files where they are called.

Comment: i got it what do you mean by: functions are always extern by default. at first i thought functions can be called across implementation files without including header and without `extern`ing it. i was wrong.

Comment: @Donotalo A function declaration `R func(T arg)` tells the compiler that there is a function called `func` which returns a value of type `R` and has a formal parameter of type `T` called `arg`. This allows the use of the function name in the context of the declaration. The linker is responsible for resolving such a name and find the corresponding function definition which might can be found in a different compilation unit.

Answer (score -3):

One use of `extern` functions is that suppose you have two modules: module_a (implemented in `module_a.h` and `module_a.c` files), module_b (implemented in `module_b.h` and `module_b.c` files). Now you want a specific function of module_b to use in module_a. But you don't want to expose all the functionality of module_b into module_a. So that case instead of `#include "module_b.h"` you can `extern` the required function prototype only.

Comment: As discussed in the comments to my answer, use of `extern` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Oli: I've just tested this feature using VS2008. It didn't work except `extern`. Any idea why? I have 3 files: main.cpp (contains main()), functions.h and functions.cpp. functions.cpp defines a function (named fun()) that just returns 0. from main(), i called `cout << fun() << endl;` compiler says fun() is undeclared. then i wrote `extern int fun();` before main(). then it worked.

Answer (score -3):

Isn't it enough to declare prototype in your *.c file before use of function, instead of including whole header file ? No need to use extern in any case for functions.  I have not try yet but it suppose to work that way.